# How to undsestand "hence the name by which they are known and ending with the Lateran Treaty of 1929"?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-structure, past-continuous

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_of_Rome

The whole sentence is:

> The agreements were signed in the Lateran Palace, hence the name by which they are known and ending with the Lateran Treaty of 1929, where the Holy See renounced its claims over most of the city of Rome in return for Italy's recognition of the Vatican State.

I'm confused about both the structure and the tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mispunctuated, and very clumsy.

First, "hence the name by which they are known" is a parenthetical clause, which needs a closing comma.

Secondly, "and ending with ... " is syntactically odd. It can just about be parsed as modifying "were signed", but it's awkward.

I've just been over to Wikipedia and rewritten it. It now reads

> The agreements were signed in the Lateran Palace, from which they take their name. They culminated in the Lateran Treaty of 1929, where the Holy See renounced its claims over most of the city of Rome in return for Italy's recognition of the Vatican State.